# jQuery sidebar will toggle, but won't slideback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery slider that when clicked, will fire the else before the if. I am not to sure why this is doing this. I need it so when the element is

If any one knows how to fix this, that would be great!

```html
<div class="sidebar-mob" onclick="sidebarPull()">
  <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
</div>
```

```js
function sidebarPull(element) {
  if ($(element).data('clicked')) {
    $(".content").css("margin-left", "100%");
    $(".sidebar").css("margin-left", "-7%");
    $(".sidebar-mob i").css("transform", "180deg")
    console.log("if-clicked");
    $(element).data('clicked', false)
  } else {
    $(".content").css("margin-left", "0%");
    $(".sidebar").css("margin-left", "-100%");
    $(".sidebar-mob i").css("transform", "180deg")
    $(element).data('clicked', true)
    console.log("else-clicked");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the `element` argument in to the function. Add `this` to the function call:

```
<div class="sidebar-mob" onclick="sidebarPull(this)">
  <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
</div>
```

That being said, you can tidy this up a lot by using unobtrusive event handlers. Inline event handlers are outdated and should be avoided where possible. Try this:

```html
<div class="sidebar-mob">
  <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sidebar-mob').click(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var clicked = $el.data('clicked');
    $(".content").css("margin-left", clicked ? "100%" : '0%');
    $(".sidebar").css("margin-left", clicked ? "-7%" : '-100%');
    $(".sidebar-mob i").css("transform", "180deg")
    $el.data('clicked', !clicked)
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah awesome, all works now. Will award you the answer as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note that I updated the answer to include a pure-jQuery version too